# Complex query with filters in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filter, entity-framework-core

I have a model with only 3 classes: `User`, `Filter` and `FilterEntry`.

```
class Filter 
{
    public List<FilterEntry> Inclusions { get; set; } 
    public List<FilterEntry> Exclusions { get; set; } 
}

public class FilterEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

A `Filter` is filter that was persisted to the DB, you can see it like a definition of a filter. It contains one or more `FilterEntries` that define the filter. The Inclusions and Exclusions are the restrictions that apply to the filter.

An example:

```
var filter = new Filter 
    { 
       Inclusions = new[] { new FilterEntry { Age = 33 } }, 
       Exclusions = new[] { new FilterEntry { Name = "John" }, new FilterEntry { Name = "Peter" } }, 
    };
```

This defines a `Filter` that will represent people aged 33, except for who are called "John" or "Peter". So, when this filter is applied to the Users, it should return all the users that are 33, except for Johns and Peters.

Now the problem. How do I create a query using Entity Framework that, given a Filter, returns the Users according to it?

I don't even know how to start! All I have is this:

```
Filter filter = dbContext.Filters.First(x => x.FilterId == filterId);
var filteredUsers = from u in dbContext.Users
     where ... // user is any of the in filter.Inclusions
     where ... // user is not in any of the filter.Exclusions
     select u;
```

NOTICE that Filter and FilterEntry keep a 1-N relationship. I omitted the keys to simplify the code.

Comment: Are the filters always going to be name/age or did you exclude other filter requirements?

Comment: Yes, I excluded some filters for the sake of simplicity, but for example, the FilterEntry could contain a navigation property, for instance Country, that would specify a Country to include/exclude if it's specified. A null value in any of the properties of the FilterEntry means that a given filter field is not set. For instance, a FilterEntry with all the properties to null, but with Country means that only the Country will apply. That's why Age is nullable. Null determines when a filter to a member applies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to build a dynamic where clause, so I would recommend [`PredicateBuilder`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder).  I haven't tested the code below, but you would want something like...

```
Filter filter = dbContext.Filters.First(x => x.FilterId == filterId);

var pb = new PredicateBuilder<User>();

foreach(var inclusion in filter.Inclusions)
{
    if(inclusion.Age.HasValue) 
    {
        pb = pb.And(p => p.Age == inclusion.Age.Value);
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inclusion.Name))
    {
        pb = pb.And(p => p.Name == inclusion.Name);
    }
}

foreach(var exclusion in filter.Exclusions)
{
    if(exclusion.Age.HasValue) 
    {
        pb = pb.And(p => p.Age != exclusion.Age.Value);
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exclusion.Name))
    {
        pb = pb.And(p => p.Name != exclusion.Name);
    }
}

var filteredUsers = dbContext.Users.AsExpandable().Where(pb);
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Lease. How would this change if we included a member Country member to the FilterEntry to include/exclude a Country? Will this be solution still be valid? And if there were nested filters like Couple.CountryOfBirth?

Comment: Eric, which package should I install to use PredicateBuilder in ASP.NET Core 2.

Comment: I have found it. It's LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar scenario arise where I wanted to be able to specify dynamic filters like that. I ended up using the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` NuGet package to help (https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core). This allows you to run Linq queries using string inputs. Then, rather than having to build a Linq expression tree from your `Filter`, you just need to construct a where clause as a string.

```
public class Filter
{
    public List<FilterEntry> Inclusions { get; set; }
    public List<FilterEntry> Exclusions { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<User> ApplyTo<User>(IQueryable<User> queryable)
    {
        // TODO: Dynamically build this string instead of hard-coding it.
        //       You would probably iterate through Inclusions and Exclusions
        //       appending to the where clause as you go.
        var whereClause = "Age == @0 && Name != @1 && Name != @2";
        var params = new object[] { 33, "John", "Peter" };

        return queryable.Where(whereClause, params);
    }
}
```

I realise this isn't a working solution, but hopefully it at least gives you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I used for my project:

```
  public async Task<SocialListViewModel> GetPagedListAsyncResultSearch(SocialSearchRequestResultSearch request, List<string> fields)
    {

        //Begin Conditions

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Social>();


        if (request.Id_parvandeh != 0)
        {
            if (request.logic_Id_parvandeh.Equals("And")) predicate = predicate.And(a => a.Id_parvandeh == request.Id_parvandeh);
            else predicate = predicate.Or(a => a.Id_parvandeh == request.Id_parvandeh);
        }
}
```